# dhclient says it's bound to address - but ifconfig doesn't

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp, ifconfig, dhclient

I started `dhclient` with:

`syslog:`

```
...
Dec 27 03:26:03 HOST dhclient[13412]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x859ef640)
Dec 27 03:26:03 HOST dhclient[13435]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.199 on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x40f69e85)
Dec 27 03:26:03 HOST dhclient[13435]: DHCPOFFER of 192.168.1.199 from 192.168.1.1
Dec 27 03:26:03 HOST dhclient[13435]: DHCPACK of 192.168.1.199 from 192.168.1.1
Dec 27 03:26:03 HOST dhclient[13435]: bound to 192.168.1.199 -- renewal in 1045201 seconds.
```

Looks like it worked, but `ifconfig` doesn't show the address:

```
ifconfig enp4s0
enp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:08:a2:48:48:48
          inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::208:a2ff:fe0c:f648/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1189 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:23 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:135707 (135.7 KB)  TX bytes:2264 (2.2 KB)
          Memory:dfd00000-dfd1ffff
```

- Is there a way to fix it?
- For my current test, 192.168.1.199 answer to `ping`, but sometimes it doesn't.

-- Edit --

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet manual
```

- I start `dhclient` manually

-- Edit --

```
 ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:08:a2:48:48:48 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.1/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enp4s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.1.199/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global secondary enp4s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::208:a2ff:fe0c:f648/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Check whether the `enp4s0` interface is configured to take ipv4 from `dhcp` or static IP is assigned to the interface.

Comment: It's manual - I start `dhclient` manually

Comment: What does `ip addr` say? Why are you running `dhclient` on the DHCP server (`192.168.1.1`)?

Comment: I posted the output of `ip addr`. This is not the dhcp server, that's just the default ip before getting a new one from `dhclient`

Comment: Now we can see that the host does indeed have `192.168.1.199` as it's IP address, but as a secondary. The original `192.168.1.1` is still there as primary. Where does it get this "default" address from?

Comment: When using `dhclient`, is there a way to tell him "take the primary" ? This default gets from my application: on startup the app configures this ip statically. Afterwards when telling the app I'm using dhcp, it starts `dhclient` and use 'manual'

Comment: I don't think so. If you are doing things manually, you could perhaps delete the static address right before running dhclient? Is there some reason why the host cannot be configured using DHCP from the start?

Comment: I do delete it manually. I change the `/etc/network/interfaces` file and do `service networking restart`. Yes, I'm developing some "out of the box" machine. The initial configuration is this static ip - and not the `dhcp` by requirement :/

Comment: I'll try using `ip addr flush dev enp4s0` before starting the `dhclient` and see if it helps

Comment: Another option I'll try https://library.netapp.com/ecmdocs/ECMP1114171/html/GUID-FC52D936-5934-4DE6-9C11-D9677B9DFADE.html

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Johan Myréen I realized through the command `ip addr`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:08:a2:48:48:48 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.1/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enp4s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.1.199/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global secondary enp4s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::208:a2ff:fe0c:f648/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

That for some reason the interface `enp4s0` has a *primary* and *secondary* addresses, where the `dhcp` ip is on the *secondary* address for some unknown reason.

Though I don't know the reason - what helps solve this issue is calling

```
ip addr flush dev enp4s0
```

Which flush the interface - then I *start clean* when allocating the *dhcp address*